# How can I setup nvcc to use Visual C++ Express 2010 x64 from Windows SDK 7.1?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, cuda, winapi, nvcc

I'm building 64-bit apps with Visual C++ Express 2010 extended with Windows SDK 7.1 (to add 64 bit compiler). When I use nvcc in 32-bits mode it works well. When I use it in 64-bits mode I get this error:

```
nvcc fatal   : Visual Studio configuration file '(null)' could not be found for installation at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64/../../..'
```

What can I do to supply the correct files to nvcc?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've found solution. Nvcc is looking for vcvars64.bat file to be in `Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64`, but it exists only in professional version of VS. You have to create it manually putting inside:
`CALL setenv /x64`

Comment: Even in VS Pro, I have this problem. Why is Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64 the relevant directory? how does one adapt this solution if the compiler is located in a different path?